# My brother's annoyingly clever message

Tags: riddle, visual

My brother James sent me this message: "You know Austin, I know what Mom likes and does not. Figure it out if you can!"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your brother has found a clever way to say

> "Mom likes ME but not U (you)"

Images:

> geoMEtry | CalcUlus or fUnctions
>  oMEga | taU
>  eMErgency | U-turn
>  coMEt | satUrn
>  And as a bonus (credit op): jaMEs | aUstin

> The things she likes contain "ME"; the things she does not like contain "U"!

Comment: Superb. And don't forget our names!! James and Austin.